# How to check a list of nodes follows an ordered path in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a list of nodes stored as a chain in my neo4j graph database as given below:

> root node1->neo4j->graph ->database.
>   root node2->neo4j->graph -> search.
>   root node3->neo4j->internals.

If I give a list of nodes(populated dynamically) as input , for e.g. “neo4j graph database”, I want to check for the given sequence of nodes and return the root folder.i.e.

> neo4j graph database->root node1.
>
> neo4j graph ->root node1, root node2.
>
> neo4j ->root node1, root node2, root node3.

---

Answer (score 0):

First off, here is some data that looks like your sample. I made some assumptions that the data listed were all separate strands.

```
create (r1:Root {name: 'Root 1'})
create (n1:Node {name: 'Neo4j'})
create (n2:Node {name: 'Graph'})
create (n3:Node {name: 'Database'})
create r1-[:CONNECTED]->n1-[:CONNECTED]->n2-[:CONNECTED]->n3
create (r2:Root {name: 'Root 2'})
create (n4:Node {name: 'Neo4j'})
create (n5:Node {name: 'Graph'})
create (n6:Node {name: 'Search'})
create r2-[:CONNECTED]->n4-[:CONNECTED]->n5-[:CONNECTED]->n6
create (r3:Root {name: 'Root 3'})
create (n7:Node {name: 'Neo4j'})
create (n8:Node {name: 'Internals'})
create r3-[:CONNECTED]->n7-[:CONNECTED]->n8
return *
```

Now, here is a solution that works for ordered lists.  The 0.. enables it to work with ordered lists with only one node.

```
// start with the ordered list of node names
with ['Neo4j', 'Graph', 'Database'] as ordered_list
// start by matching paths that begin with the first node
// in the ordered list and end with the last node
match p=((a:Node {name: ordered_list[0]})-[:CONNECTED*0..]-(b:Node {name: ordered_list[length(ordered_list)-1]}))
// collect these as the list of potential candidates
with collect(p) as candidates, ordered_list
// pass through the list and only keep the candidates that are 
// the same length as the ordered list
unwind candidates as candidate
with case when (length(nodes(candidate)) = length(ordered_list)) 
  then candidate
end as candidate, ordered_list
// recollect the filtered candidates
with collect(candidate) as candidates, ordered_list
// pass through the candidates now again and compare the names
// of the ordered list to the original ordered list
// only keep those that match as matched
unwind candidates as candidate
with case 
  when reduce(names = [], n in nodes(candidate) | names + n.name) = ordered_list 
  then candidate
end as matched
// with the matched nodes find the root node that is attached to
// first node in each matched path
match (r:Root)--(head:Node)
where id(head) = id(nodes(matched)[0])
// return the root and the matched path nodes
return r.name, nodes(matched)
```

Comment: In my database , only one node will be created for each unique word say "neo4j", only additional relationship with root properties will be added so that each node can have multiple incoming relationships. In this scenario, how to retrieve the correct root name for which all the matched selected nodes have same value.

Comment: i don't think you can possibly retrieve a distinct root node per each path unless you are not supplying all of the information. Given your sample data, in that model I see three separate "root nodes" with relationships to neo4j. There will be way to distinctly match the chains to a specific root unless there is more information on each node about its ultimate root node. And if that were the case the query would likely be simpler.

Comment: I tried and got the answer from your answer itself..                                        WITH extract( r IN rels(matched)| r.sourcename)...........